# Tampering With Control Text in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I was recently discussing this with someone, and I wasn't sure if this is an issue or not.

We are creating an ASP.NET website and if the user performs an action on a page we might create a database query using the Text values on controls that we have previously populated.

Could a user do something malicious like modify the text of a label control in their browser, then hit the update button and when we pull that label's .Text we end up inserting that value into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easily done via firebug, for example, yes. Make sure you sanitize/validate any input coming in to prevent SQL injection or any other malicious intent.

Have a read of this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx) for more help.

Comment: I know you can easily edit the text in the browser. My question was will that new text be sent back and used when the user clicks the Update button?

Comment: @user768600 - You can easily test in firebug: **no**, it wouldn't send changed value for label because it will be loaded from viewstate, not form the control. But controls like HiddenField can be tempered and **yes**, tempered value will be sent to the server unless you takes preventive measures suggested here.